# Objective c - how to display a shorter name of viewController on back button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, back-button

I almost sure I saw someday that there is some property to set a shorter name of viewController to be display in the back button when it push another viewController and become the back viewController.
Can some one remind me what is this property?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        // Custom initialization
    self.title = @"First View Controller";

    // this defines the back button leading BACK TO THIS controller
    UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
      initWithTitle:@"Back"
      style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
      target:nil
      action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;
    [backBarButtonItem release];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

self.navigationItem.title = @"short name";

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious to see what the "right" answer is. Personally I change the name of the last controller (like the root), which works.

```
-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super navigationController:navigationController willShowViewController:viewController animated:animated];
    UIViewController *root = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    if (something)
        root.title = @"Apply";
    else
        root.title = "Root"
}
```

This works identically to `self.navigationItem.title` in all regards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize the `backBarButtonItem` from the `navigationItem` in your parent view controller.